# Verificar subprocesso em execução

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Quando minha aplicação inicia preciso verificar se um programa de terceiros está rodando, caso não estiver, preciso iniciá-lo.

O problema é que o programa feito em Java e quando está sendo executado ele roda dentro do próprio Java, como na imagem:

[image: Programa rodando]

Como posso identificar se o programa está rodando? Já utilizei alguns métodos que encontrei para verificar os processos rodando no windows só que a maioria apenas identifica o processo *"javaw.exe"* e eu quero identificar o Demander Sincronizador.

**Obs.:** Não posso buscar pelo titulo da janela, pois ele muda

> Utilizo Delphi RAD Studio XE10.2 Berlin

Comment: Por curiosidade se iniciar o processo mesmo que ele já esteja em execução irá duplicar o mesmo?

Comment: Não, ele abre apenas uma vez, quando o processo já está rodando é exibido uma mensagem dizendo que apenas uma aplicação pode ser aberta por vez

Comment: Espere por uma resposta pois não conheço Delphi, mas caso não exista uma solução viável pode sempre fazer o inverso e capturar esse erro.

Answer (score 1):

É possível fazer a busca utilizando as funções [Process32First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834(v=vs.85).aspx)/[Process32Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms684836(v=vs.85).aspx) do windows, fazendo um loop nos processos existentes para buscar pelo nome do executável por exemplo. Para seu caso poderia fazer inicialmente uma busca pelo Java, depois fazer um segundo loop nos processos filhos(comparando o ID do processo pai), para verificar se sua aplicação esta rodando.

Exemplo:

```
uses
  TlHelp32, System.Generics.Collections;


function RetornaPID(exeFileName: string): integer;
var
  ContinueLoop: BOOL;
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
  FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  Result := -1;
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if (UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) =  UpperCase(ExeFileName))
    or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) = UpperCase(ExeFileName)) then
    begin
      Result := FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID;
      break;
    end;
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;

Function RetornaListaprocessosFilhos(aIDProcessoPai: Integer): TList<Integer>;
var
  ContinueLoop: BOOL;
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
  FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  Result := TList<Integer>.Create;
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, aIDProcessoPai);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if FProcessEntry32.th32ParentProcessID = aIDProcessoPai then
    begin
      Result.add(FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID);
    end;
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vPIDPai: Integer;
  vPIDFilho: Integer;
  vListaProcessosFilhos: TList<Integer>;
begin
  vPIDPai := RetornaPID('explorer.exe');
  if vPIDPai <> -1 then
  begin
    vListaProcessosFilhos := RetornaListaprocessosFilhos(vPIDPai);
    for vPIDFilho in vListaProcessosFilhos do
    begin
      ShowMessage(format('Id do processo filho: %d', [vPIDFilho]));
    end;
    FreeAndNil(vListaProcessosFilhos);
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('process não encontrado');
end;
```

Referencia de utilização do Process32...: [DelphiTricks](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/windows/check_if_a_process_is_running.html)

Comment: Assim que eu tiver um tempo realizo alguns testes com esse método e dou um feedback

Comment: Esse método é igual aos outros que eu já testei... Ele só chega a encontrar o processo "javaw.exe" e eu quero é saber se o processo "Demander Sincronizador" está rodando dentro deste "javaw.exe".

Você sabe me dizer se utilizando este método eu consigo procurar pelos processos "javaw.exe" e depois verificar quais são seus subprocessos?

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro, resposta editada!

Comment: São métodos muitos legais que eu desconhecia, mas mesmo assim ainda não serviu para o que preciso, vou mudar minha lógica e tentar usar o CreateProcess para abrir o programa de terceiro e guardar o ID do mesmo para futuras verificações.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem?

Eu estava com o mesmo problema. Resolvi usando um excelente blog de um MVP Embarcadero que já me ajudou muito em outras oportunidades. Nesse blog, ele posta um exemplo onde é possível conseguir a propriedade "*CommandLine*", que traz os subprocessos que estão rodando pelo "*javaw.exe*". Dessa forma, consigo buscar o que quero no retorno em texto usando, por exemplo, um **Pos** para determinar se o nome do processo que quero está sendo executado.

Por exemplo, tenho dois programas Java instalados e rodando em meu PC. Se quero um chamado "*MyApp*", faço o código postado pelo blog com pequenas adaptações para buscar o "*MyApp*" na sequência. Segue o código:

```
const
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;// classe Winapi.ActiveX
  iValue        : LongWord;
  vConteudo     : string;
begin
      vConteudo := '';
      FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator'); // para usar o "CreateOleObject" precisa da classe System.Win.ComObj
      FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
      FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT Name, CommandLine FROM Win32_Process Where Name="%s"',['javaw.exe']),'WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
      oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
      while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
      begin // função pega em https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/11/06/wmi-tasks-using-delphi-%E2%80%93-processes/
        vConteudo := vConteudo + Format('Name         %s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]);
        vConteudo := vConteudo + Format('Command Line %s',[String(FWbemObject.CommandLine)]);
        FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
      end;

      if Pos('MyApp',vConteudo) > 0 then
        ShowMessage('achou')
      else
        ShowMessage('não achou');
```

Repare que, entre os processos que está sendo buscado na *Win32_Process*, eu procuro como nome o '*javaw.exe*' (indicando que a VM do Java está executando). Depois, após trazer o resultado, busco dentro da variável que carreguei com todo o conteúdo (chamada de "*vConteudo*") se o que desejo encontra se encontra ali.

Pelo menos pra mim, tem funcionado perfeitamente. Já rodei em Windows 10 (64 e 32 bits) e Windows 7 (32 bits). Mas acredito que deva funcionar em outros Windows também - lembrando que ela só funciona em Windows, nada de Linux, por exemplo.

Espero ter sido claro em minha explicação.

Créditos para o autor, Rodrigo Ruz, em: https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/11/06/wmi-tasks-using-delphi-%E2%80%93-processes/

PS: utilizo Rad Studio 10 Seattle

Comment: Obrigado! Na verdade acabei criando um projeto próprio meu em Delphi e integrando o mesmo ao meu projeto principal, assim não dependendo mais da aplicação de terceiros. Assim que tiver um tempo analiso melhor sua resposta.